# Why SW_HIDE does not hide console window during Inno Setup compilation?

Tags: inno-setup

Pre-processor instruction:

```
#expr Exec( \
    "powershell", "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File UpdateDatabaseVersionInfo.ps1", \
    SourcePath, SW_HIDE)
```

It works fine. But it shows a PowerShell window. But I passed `SW_HIDE`.

Can that be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SW_*` values go to the fifth argument of the [`Exec` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=exec). Pass default non-zero value to the fourth "wait" argument:

```
#expr Exec("powershell", "...", SourcePath, 1, SW_HIDE)
```